# Call to object won't work in another file

Tags: python

I'm using a code I found on Github and I'm trying to run it. However there's an error that says:

```
File "/home/anatole2/WVD/SymJAX/symjax/tensor/base.py", line 253, in jax_wrap
    symjax._fn_to_op[func] = op
AttributeError: module 'symjax' has no attribute '_fn_to_op'
```

I tried to find `_fn_to_op` in every python file and could only find this in `__init__.py`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# flake8: noqa


_fn_to_op = {}
from . import probabilities
from . import nn
from . import tensor
from . import data
from . import rl

from .base import *
from ._version import get_versions

__version__ = get_versions()["version"]
del get_versions


_graphs = [Graph("default")]
__all__ = ["data", "tensor", "nn", "probabilities", "rl"]
```

When I changed the path to `symjax.__init__._fn_to_op` I get the same error. I know `_fn_to_op` is not a function/attribute in that file but it's the only one I found. What does the function do and how can I fix the error?

Here's the code that generates the error:

```
def jax_wrap(func, doc_func=None):
    if doc_func is None:
        doc_func = func

    @wraps(doc_func)
    def op(*args, seed=None, **kwargs):

        # if there is a name we remove it for now to use the jax tracer
        op_name = kwargs.pop("name", None)

        # first we check if we are in a random function to be careful
        # with the key. this is just to get shape and dtype so we do not bother
        # to use the correct seed yet
        is_random = func in symjax.tensor.random._RANDOM_FUNCTIONS
        temp_args = ((jax.random.PRNGKey(0),) if is_random else ()) + args
        tree = get_output_tree(func, *temp_args, **kwargs)

        # now we determine what type of Tensor subclass it will produce
        feed = {"_jax_function": func, "name": op_name}
        if type(tree) == list or type(tree) == tuple:
            feed.update(
                {
                    "_shapes": [t.shape for t in tree],
                    "_dtypes": [t.dtype for t in tree],
                }
            )
            if func == jax.numpy.shape:
                return Shape(
                    *args,
                    **feed,
                    **kwargs,
                )
            else:
                return MultiOutputOp(
                    *args,
                    **feed,
                    **kwargs,
                )
        else:
            feed.update({"_shape": tree.shape, "_dtype": tree.dtype})
            if is_random:
                return RandomOp(*args, _seed=seed, **feed, **kwargs)
            else:
                return Op(*args, **feed, **kwargs)
    symjax._fn_to_op[func] = op
    if not hasattr(func, "__doc__") or func.__doc__ is None:
        return op

    if doc_func is not None:
        op.__name__ = func.__name__
    return op
```

Comment: Have you tried to contact the author of the code?

Comment: Can you add the code that generates the error?